# How can I change the color of a button each time I try to click on it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question recording to the code I wrote today. I know that I can change the backgroundcolor of the button, but just once (with: `button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;`). But now, I have a problem.
The color should change each time I try to click on the button. How does it work? Thank you for your help.

This is my code. I programmed something funny: when you try to click the button, it disappears and appears elsewhere :).
¨

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    public Form1() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Random cox = new Random();

    private void button2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = cox.Next(500);
        int y = cox.Next(500);
        button2.Left = x;
        button2.Top = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is changing the colour to yellow, but because it stays yellow.. you dont see the change

Comment: Use a `random` to generate three values between 0 and 255, then use `Color.FromArgb()` when the button is pressed to set the colour.

Comment: Store the possible colors in a `Color[]`, then use the `Random` to pick one: `var nextColor = colorArray[cox.Next(colorArray.Length)];`

Comment: @Equalsk: Could you send me an example, please? I don`t know the expression "Color.FromArgb()" ( I`ve never used it before). Thanks

Comment: I`ll try it @TimSchmelter , Thank you

Comment: Zohar has beaten me to it, see his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besically you have 2 options: Either keep an array of colors and choose a color randomly from that array on each click, or generate a random color on each click.

option 1:

```
// inside your form:
Color[] colors = new Color[] {Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Red};

// inside the button click event handler:
button2.BackColor = colors[col.Next(0,colors.Length)];
```

option2:

```
// inside the button click event handler:

button2.BackColor = new Color(col.Next(0,256), col.Next(0,256), col.Next(0,256));
```

Of course, both options use the `Random` instance named `col` in the code you provided.

Comment: `button2.BackColor = colors[col.Next(0,colors.Length)];` might be slightly better.

Comment: My answer was going to be very much the same :0 you beat me to it. But seriously with colours you will get far better results if you use the array option. Random components is fun but can look horrible.

Comment: I totally agree. I once had a project where I needed to show a graph with random colors, and had to build them with the second option. I had to use some code to ensure the colors do not look too much alike but still the outcome could sometimes be horrible to look at.